# XMLHttpRequest.open() exception handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, exception, xmlhttprequest

I have the following piece of code (only relevant parts):

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET",doc_name,false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
if(xmlDoc==null)
{
   xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(defaultXml);
}
```

This runs fine as I load a default xml file if the specified file does not exist but shows a 404 error only in the console if the file does not exist. (This error does not reflect anywhere in the page except the console).

My question is that how should I check for this exception & **is it necessary to add an extra piece of code for checking the existence of the file when the code runs without it?**

Comment: Try this one, I geuss you're looking for this:
[AJAX - The onreadystatechange Event](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the HTTP response code via `xhttp.status`; either a `200` (OK) or `304` (Not Modified) would normally be considered a successful request.

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET",doc_name,false);
xhttp.send();

if (xhttp.status === 200 || xhttp.status === 304) {
    xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
    if(xmlDoc==null)
    {
       xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(defaultXml);
    }
}
```

Make sure you're declaring your variables first using `var`, otherwise you'll have implicit globals, which are bad.

Also make sure you have a good reason for doing this synchronously; synchronous XHR's lock up the browser whilst the request is pending. Making it async is ***highly*** recommended.

For the second part of your question, there's no problem what-so-ever; as long as your app can handle the exception. (which is seems to do)

Comment: yup I know that, I am declaring variables using var & am making it sync (for a reason), the file is small, so making it sync isn't a problem.

Comment: But should I really need to do this checking as the code is running fine without it? Any disadvantages of the error in the console?

Comment: @gopi1410: There's no problem what-so-ever; as long as your app can handle it (which is seems to do).